# Media queries in less with variables-need global variables

Tags: css, global-variables, less

I am looking for a solution where I define 1 variable globally and than overwrite it inside a media query - without putting the entire code in it (like [LESS CSS set variables in media query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906114/less-css-set-variables-in-media-query)).

I thought something like that(defining):

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
     @BWInputHeight: 40px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    //responsive screens
    @BWInputHeight: 20px;
}
```

And using it like that:

```
.dataTables_filter input {
    .form-control;
    max-width: 135px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: @BWInputHeight;
    padding: 1px 6px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

The problem here, "@BWInputHeight" is a undeclared variable. How can I solve this with LESS ?

Comment: by the way I use dotless

Comment: How about using list arrays like [this](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/GmzCD)? Click on the eye icon in the CSS tab to see the compiled output. Or is this exactly what you didn't want to do?

Comment: Yes, this it not what I wanted. I need something like     media (min-width: 768px) {
     BWInputHeight: 40px;//here i define only varibles, which will be used depending on the resolution,so I have for example .dataTables_filter input {} only in one place, because if I add some new properties may be I forget to add it also on different media queries
} Thank you for helping me :)

Comment: I have updated the same pen, check if this is anywhere closer :)

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't note that. This is less.js. I have never tried with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort of achieve this by using list arrays for each property and screen-width (like the below sample):

```
@BWInputHeight: '20px','40px','60px'; // Height of the button for min-width=320 and min-width=768 respectively
@minwidths: '320px','768px','1024px'; // The widths for which you need the media queries to be created

.loop-column(@index) when (@index > 0) { // Loop to iterate through each value in @minwidths and form the corresponding output
    .loop-column(@index - 1);
    @width:  extract(@minwidths, @index); // extracts width based on array index
    @media (min-width: e(@width)){
          .dataTables_filter input{
            height: e(extract(@BWInputHeight,@index)); // extracts button height for the corresponding screen width
            max-width: 135px;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 1px 6px;
            margin-right: 15px;          
          }
    }
}

.loop-column(length(@minwidths)); // calling the function
```

[**Demo in Code-pen**](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/GmzCD) - Modify output area width to see difference and click the eye icon in CSS tab to see compiled CSS.

**Note:** As per this [Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377990/is-dotless-the-same-exact-syntax-as-the-less-css-language), both dotless and less.js should be 99% compatible and hence I have given this answer. In case this doesn't work for you, I will happily have this answer removed.

Comment: Thanks for helping again. I use dotless 1.4.0.0 and installed Less.js 1.5.1 over vs nuget manager, but as soon as I excecute this code there is no ".dataTables_filter input" class- so from my point of view it means, there is some problem with rendering that code ?!. What can I do to find that error, may there is something left to configure before using less.js ?!

Comment: Sorry mate, I have no clues either. I am trying with less.js 1.5.1 and it seems to work fine.

Comment: I left out the "@" signs, this is the output from different inspectors from your presvious code: "@BWInputHeight: '200px','40px';
min-width: ~"(min-width: 768px)";
max-width: ~"(max-width: 768px)";

.dataTables_filter input {
      
      max-width: 135px;
     display: inline-block;
     media @min-width{
      height: e(extract(@BWInputHeight,1))
    }
    media @max-width{
      height: e(extract(@BWInputHeight,2))
    }
      padding: 1px 6px;
      margin-right: 15px;
 }" but the current code does not show any output...

Comment: No idea mate. From whatever I read on the net, they should work fine but not sure why it is not :( Will let you know if I find any solution. But leaving out the @ symbol won't help because it is required for variable identification.

Comment: ok thanks, i left out "@" because stackoverflow gives me an error when I use more than 2 of "@"

Comment: Oh ok, I thought you had left them out from the code :D By the way, check if [link 1](http://jordanwallwork.co.uk/2012/08/debugging-less-compilation-errors/) or [link 2](http://tedgustaf.com/blog/2010/11/setup-dotless-in-aspnet-project/) has any helpful information for you.

Comment: @user254197: Did it get solved? Were those links of any help?

Comment: actually it did not work by now, I guess because the links are for old versions for example, I added in the web.config " <dotless minifyCss="false" cache="false" logger="dotless.Core.Loggers.AspResponseLogger" />"  and I got that error:  "Parser Error Message: Sections must only appear once per config file.  See the help topic <location> for exceptions."

Comment: and the web.config(...mvc\Web.config) looks like "<configuration>
  <configSections>
       <section name="dotless" type="dotless.Core.configuration.DotlessConfigurationSectionHandler, dotless.Core" />
  </configSections>
  <dotless minifyCss="false" cache="false" logger="dotless.Core.Loggers.AspResponseLogger" />
  </configuration>"

Comment: now I changed to web essentials 2013 and it works :)

Comment: Great. Happy to be of some help :)

Comment: Hi, again. How shall I change the current code if I only have 2 media queries like "@media (min-width: 768px)" and "@media (max-width: 768px)" and not "@minwidths: '320px','768px','1024px';" only min-width ?
Or if I only want to have 320px defined as max-width from  "@minwidths: '320px','768px','1024px';" ?

Comment: If you have only two then writing them separately could be a bit more easier than a loop. However if you still want have a look at [this](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/GmzCD). It is a very quickish sample just to show you how it can be done. Please optimize before using.